# Break multi-column div

Tags: jquery, css, multiple-columns

I'm using CSS3 multi-column to get a print magazine look to my blog, but longer posts don't fit entirely on the screen and require awkward scrolling. Is there a way to break into, say, 500px high divs so that a reader can read one 3-column block of text before having to scroll?

I tried using jQuery to insert a `column-span: all` span every 6 paragraphs, but that gives inconsistent height results.

Any ideas?

Here's an [example post](http://riggl.es/post/16847560083/the-real-cost-of-digital) (warning: columns don't work in IE, sorry. that's another issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scratch all those suggestions down below. I've found exactly what you need. You need CSS3 regions. It allows you to set the overflow from one region to flow into another region. Just set your height and then set the CSS3 commands for flow `flow-into: whatever;` and `flow-from: whatever;`. Presto! use prefixes for each browser like `-webkit-flow-into: whatever;`

---

I think you'll need javascript for this. The column span all was a good idea because it will break it up like you need to to, but it's hard to get the `<hr />` or whatever you used to be in the right place vertically. I found a link that has some code to detect overflow and place it in another div. I didn't check to see if it works or not but it's a good idea.

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=200616

You could also insert an element with `column-span: all` based on a character count, which would be much more consistent than a paragraph count.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering about this character count possibility. I'm no JS expert - at all. Easy way to do this? Maybe this function is included in jQuery?

Comment: Updated my answer. Check it out.